# Android Radiobutton listener inside custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have an application which populates a custom listview using an array adapter of custom type. The binding is done in getView of custom array adapter class. Currently I've added a custom logic which checks which radio button is selected and deselects previously checked radiobutton when a new one is selected. I wish to make it cleaner so that I can manage these radiobutton(inside a Listview row) via radiogroups. how do I add a listener for such a radiobutton.
Also, can I update the parent layout (show or hide a button) of the listview based on checking a radiobutton in the listview row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is one radio per row then you can't add a Radio child to a RadioGroup outside its parent view. In this case the radio parent view is the one that you inflate in a getView. So if you want to try to achieve Radio-selection-like on row click then you have to maintain it like the one you do in your custom logic.

Comment: that means its better to do without it and have an OnItemClickListener itself

Comment: Yes, and please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) look for Do and Don't section for better perspective of ListView

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this documentation about [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)?
Simply add the Group to your ListRow and set a custom RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener where you can handle everything